# Função com dois parênteses? funcao()()

Tags: javascript, react

Não sei como descrever por isso não consegui achar informação sobre. kkk

No final do código ao exportar o "connect", o que faz o segundo parêntesis? Como se chama essa sintaxe?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Sidebar = ({ modules }) => (
    <aside>
        { modules.map( itModule => (
            <div key={itModule.id}>
                <strong>{itModule.title}</strong>
                <ul> 
                    {itModule.lessons.map( itLesson =>(
                        <li key={itLesson.id}>
                            {itLesson.title}
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        ))}
    </aside>
);

export default connect( state => ({ modules: state }))(Sidebar); // <---------<<
```

Comment: Você pode dar uma olhada no código da função para matar a curiosidade também. O [`connect` exportado](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/index.js#L4) é [essa função](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/connect.js#L46)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A função `connect()` está retornando uma função. Então quando você faz `connect()(Sidebar)`, você está passando `Sidebar` como parâmetro pra função retornada por `connect` e invocando-a. Um exemplo mais simples:

```js
// Essa função recebe um parâmetro umNumero. Aí ela retorna outra função, 
// que recebe outroNumero e soma com umNumero.
function soma(umNumero) {
    return (outroNumero) => umNumero + outroNumero;
}

soma(2)(3) // 5
```

Answer (score 6):

Talvez fique mais fácil de entender a resposta do Allan Juan se você atribuir o retorno da função de alta ordem a uma variável.

```js
function soma(umNumero) {
    return (outroNumero) => umNumero + outroNumero;
}

let somaDois = soma(2) // i.e., somaDois é a função (outroNumero) => 2 + outroNumero
let somaTres = soma(3) // i.e., somaTres é a função (outroNumero) => 3 + outroNumero

let resultado1 = somaDois(3)
let resultado2 = somaTres(4)

console.log(soma(2)(3), resultado1, resultado2)
```